# GD Library Doesn't Support Jpeg Unable To Show Thumbnails

Tags: php, gd, xampp

He is my code:

```
if (function_exists('gd_info')) {
    $gda = gd_info();
    $gd['version'] = $gda['GD Version'];
    //$gd['num'] = ereg_replace('[[:alpha:][:space:]()]+','',$gda['GD Version']);
    $gd['freetype'] = $gda["FreeType Support"];
    $gd['gif_read'] = $gda["GIF Read Support"];
    $gd['gif_make'] = $gda["GIF Create Support"];
    //$gd['jpg'] = $gda["JPG Support"];
    $gd['png'] = $gda["PNG Support"];
```

The commented line produced errors:

> Function ereg_replace() is deprecated
>
> Undefined index: JPG Support

I am using XAMPP 1.7.7

Anyone knows how to fix this?

What I was trying to achieve is producing thumbnails of jpeg pictures. Now that I commented those lines. I am unable to display the thumbnails.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ereg functions have been deprecated in PHP 5.3 in favor of the [PCRE functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php). I'm not familiar with ereg syntax, but it looks like it might be  equivilant to `preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z ()]+/', '', $gda['GD Version'])`.

Furthermore, the commented line should read: `$gd['jpg'] = $gda["JPEG Support"];` i.e. JPEG with an E.

Comment: Hey you are rite :). Thx a lot bro!

Answer (score 2):

Run `phpinfo();` and see what it says under "JPEG Support". It could be that the gd-index has another name.

If it's disable, make sure you have libjpeg on your system and that gd was compiled with support for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather late but if some one else is having the same problem, use the code below:

```
if (function_exists('gd_info')) {
    $gda = gd_info();
    $gd['version'] = $gda['GD Version'];
    $gd['num'] = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z\s()]+/','',$gda['GD Version']);
    $gd['freetype'] = $gda["FreeType Support"];
    $gd['gif_read'] = $gda["GIF Read Support"];
    $gd['gif_make'] = $gda["GIF Create Support"];
    $gd['jpg'] = $gda["JPEG Support"];
    $gd['png'] = $gda["PNG Support"];
```

That should fix it real good.